# How can I get all the classes from a loaded ontology with owlapi?

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

How can I get all the classes from a loaded ontology with owlapi? Here I have an example on how to get one class, but I'm interested on accessing all the classes defined at the ontology.

```
    OWLOntologyManager manager = WLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntology(IRI.create(fileURI));
    OWLDataFactory owlDF = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
//Example to get ONE class, but I want ALL!
    OWLClass stringDocuClass = owlDF.getOWLClass(IRI.create("http://example.com/my_ontology.owl#StringDocu"));
```

I'm working with java owlapi 4.2.3 (see the API: http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `owlapi-v5.0` use:

```
ArrayList<OWLClass> classes = new ArrayList<OWLClass>();
ontology.classesInSignature().forEach(classes::add);
```

For `owlapi-v4.2.3` use:

```
Set<OWLClass> classes = ontology.getClassesInSignature();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: It is deprecated now.

Answer (score 3):

As of OWLAPI 5.0, one can use stream iterators:

```java
ArrayList<OWLClass> classes = new ArrayList<OWLClass>();
ontology.classesInSignature().forEach(classes::add);
```